# Use DER-encoded RSA public key with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I need to receive RSA public key over the wire and use it to encrypt data to send back to server. I cannot control format of key server sends, must work with current implementation.

I've implemented protocol in python,

```
key_bin = get_server_key() # "30818902818100e8ecd6f1..."
key = Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.importKey(key_bin)
padded_data = add_rsa_padding(data)
encrypted_data = key.encrypt(padded_data, 0)[0]
send_data(encrypted_data)
```

Now I'm having trouble porting it to C++ library, its preferable to use OpenSSL but I cannot find a way to load public key in non-PEM format, and converting it to PEM dynamically upon receiving seems like terrible idea. There's probably some API I've missed, can someone help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have DER encoded public key you can use `d2i_RSAPublicKey()` to convert it to OpenSSL internal structure `RSA` which then can be used with various other OpenSSL APIs to carry out your encryption